# security for sending data in angularjs (random token generation & encryption of username-password)

Tags: angularjs, security, http, encryption, token

I need to send all data with some token (rendomly generated), so that server side script can recognize it secure.

As well as, I need to encrypt username-password also for security purpose.

My client want strong security, and I never done it before. So please any one suggest me!!!

Comment: This is very broad subject which can be broken into pieces. Please research on specific subjects first and then ask whatever doubts you face. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have research for as well. I got the concept called JWT. But I am not getting hoe I can use it with AngularJS as frontend and C program(CGI) as backend. Atleast I want to clarify how I can send authenticated token from client side script (angularjs).

Comment: For proper encryption you will be using a secret key which is called salt by many now, if you will write that code on the client side using angular then user can can see your client side code so you are compromising the security. You cannot write security content on client side. Strong security doesn't meant that you need to encrypt on frontend. Just send data from client side to server side using secure channel and then before saving them in your database you proper security methods. Talking of JWT, it is used for authentication purposes.